# Python Neuroglancer Getting Input

Tags: python, voxel

Below is a snippet of code from Google's publicly available Neuroglancer.  It is from an example on their github.  Could someone explain what exactly this code does and how it does it?  I am having trouble understanding it, and don't know what exactly the variable `s` is.  Thank you for the help.

```
def my_action(s):
    print('Got my-action')
    print('  Mouse position: %s' % (s.mouse_voxel_coordinates,))
    print('  Layer selected values: %s' % (s.selected_values,))
viewer.actions.add('my-action', my_action)
with viewer.config_state.txn() as s:
    s.input_event_bindings.viewer['keyt'] = 'my-action'
    s.status_messages['hello'] = 'Welcome to this example'
```

Answer (score 0):

This example adds a key binding to the viewer and adds a status message. When you press the `t` key, the `my_action` function will run. `my_action` takes the current state of the action and grabs the mouse coordinates and selected values in the layer.

The `.txn()` method performs a state-modification transaction on the `ConfigState` object. And by state-modification, I mean it changes the config. There are several default actions in the `ConfigState` object (defined in part [here](https://github.com/google/neuroglancer/blob/566514a11b2c8477f3c49155531a9664e1d1d37a/src/neuroglancer/ui/default_input_event_bindings.ts)), and you are modifying that config by adding your own action.

The `mouse_coordinates` and `selected_values` objects are defined in Python [here](https://github.com/google/neuroglancer/blob/d71cc9014b75835d84479e242b00266437a8bd07/python/neuroglancer/viewer_config_state.py#L73-L74), and link to the typescript implementation [here](https://github.com/google/neuroglancer/blob/d71cc9014b75835d84479e242b00266437a8bd07/src/neuroglancer/python_integration/remote_actions.ts#L62-L73). The example also sets a status message on the config state, and that is implemented [here](https://github.com/google/neuroglancer/blob/fed15a96fb2e0b91670cd10fa28923f2a0f33a8a/src/neuroglancer/python_integration/remote_status_messages.ts).

It might be useful to first point to the source code for the various functions involved.

- the example is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/neuroglancer/blob/6d808b1d9bbc3cc6f8d7e6a819efb444a9fe1e0f/python/examples/example_action.py)
- [`viewer.config_state`](https://github.com/google/neuroglancer/blob/3db0fa6b46d72aeac0ea71412d8ab62ead328efb/python/neuroglancer/viewer_base.py#L67)
- `viewer.config_state` is a "trackable" version of [`neuroglancer.viewer_config_state.ConfigState`](https://github.com/google/neuroglancer/blob/d71cc9014b75835d84479e242b00266437a8bd07/python/neuroglancer/viewer_config_state.py#L155-L175)
- [`viewer.config_state.txn()`](https://github.com/google/neuroglancer/blob/3db0fa6b46d72aeac0ea71412d8ab62ead328efb/python/neuroglancer/trackable_state.py#L107-L121)

Comment: So is the above code solely for recording mouse events then?  Would I be able to do something similar for keyboard events?

Comment: Not mouse events, only mouse position. You can map actions to keyboard events, as this example does, so yes, you can do something similar for keyboard events.